# Gradle Buildship won't download dependencies

Tags: eclipse, dependencies, gradle-eclipse

I am used to using the [Eclipse Gradle plugin by Pivotal](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-0) in Luna, but now that Mars was released I am trying to use [Buildship](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship). However, I have not yet figured out how to refresh my project's dependencies.

I know that the project is set up correctly because it worked perfectly fine in Luna with the other plugin, but although importing into Mars was simple, I am getting errors because none of the dependencies have been downloaded. Am I misunderstanding the purpose of Buildship and I should switch back to the plugin by Pivotal, or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Please check .gradle directory. Most likely your dependencies are there. It's just a problem with eclipse project settings. Eclipse project doesn't know how to reference the gradle libraries.

Comment: @ATrubka Well, I have since uninstalled Buildship in favor of the plugin by Pivotal, which works without having to change any settings. I have a build.gradle file for the project (if you're curious, it was generated by the LibGdx project generator) and has always worked without me having to change any Eclipse settings.

Comment: Thank you. I also had to switch to a different plugin, which is a combination of Pivotal and Enide. Works well so far.

Comment: @StrongJoshua did you delete the .project files before trying Buildship?

Comment: @HeinrichFilter I was importing the project from a directory that is separate from my Evlipse workspace, so Mars didn't even know about Luna's .project files.

Comment: This is not a question; it should be a bug report to the Buildship project (if this still happens to its latest version).